# When I press one of my submit buttons in flask it runs both submit buttons. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

As you see there are two submit buttons when submit2 is pressed it does the same thing as submit1 and submit2. How do I make it so that when I press submit2 it only does what it is supposed to do? Here is my code below there are three files `index.html` `index2.html` `app.py` and, `forms.py`(which I did not include).

app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'REDACTED'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def main():
    form = textform()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        result = request.form
        s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='REDACTED',
                  aws_secret_access_key='REDACTED')
        # with open('input.txt','w') as f:
        #     f.truncate()
        #     f.write(result['text'])
        bucket_name = 'foodpricegooglecloud'
        file_key = 'input.txt'
        text_content = result['text']

        s3.put_object(
        Body=text_content,
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Key=file_key
        )

    # Process the result as needed
 
       
      
            #os.system('python start.py')

        # try:
        #     os.remove('walmart.csv')
        # except:
        #     pass
        # try:
        #     os.remove('target.csv')
        # except:
        #     pass
        # try:
        #     os.remove('wholefoods.csv')
        
           
        # except:
        #     pass
    

  
        walmart()
        target()
        wholefoods()
        

        # os.system('python wholefoods.py')

        # os.system('python target.py')

        # os.system('python walmart.py')



    
        s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='REDACTED',
                        aws_secret_access_key='REDACTED')
        df1 = pd.read_csv('walmart.csv')
        df2 = pd.read_csv('wholefoods.csv')
        df3 = pd.read_csv('target.csv')
        
            
    # Create a response object
        
        combined_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0)

        # Reset the index of the combined dataframe

        combined_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        try:
            combined_df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(combined_df['Price'].str.replace('$', ''))
        except:
            pass
        try:
            combined_df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(combined_df['Price'].str.replace('Now ', ''))
        except:
            pass
        combined_df.sort_values(by='Price', inplace=True)
        print(combined_df['Price'])
        # Save the combined dataframe to a new CSV file
        from io import StringIO
        combined_df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
        csv_buffer = StringIO()
        combined_df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
        bucket_name = 'foodpricegooglecloud'
        key = 'result.csv'
        s3.put_object(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue(), Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
        itemlist=[]
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key='result.csv')

        # Read the contents of the file from the response
        content = response['Body'].read()
        content = io.BytesIO(content)
        reader = csv.DictReader(content.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines())
        itemlist = list(reader)
        form2=filtersform()
        if form2.validate_on_submit():
            result2=request.form['RetailerFRes']
            newdf=combined_df.loc[combined_df['Retailer'] == result2]
            itemlist=[]
            newdf=newdf.to_dict('records')
            itemlist=list(newdf)
            print(newdf)
            #return render_template('index2.html',items=itemlist,form=form,form2=form2)

        # Decode the content assuming it's a text file (optional)
        
        
    
        return render_template('index2.html',items=itemlist,form=form,form2=form2)
    return render_template('index.html',form=form)
@app.route('/loading')
def loading():
     return render_template('loading.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css.css') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='diet.png') }}">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FoodPrice</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="form">

        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                    {{form.csrf_token}}
                    {{form.text.label}} <br>
                    {{form.text(size=30)}}
                   
                   
                    
              
            </div>
        
       
               <button class="submit-button">{{form.submit()}}</button>
            
    
        </form>
        
    </div>
    <h3>This process can take up to 60 seconds</h3>
   
        <ul>
        
            {% for item in items %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{item['Url']}}"   target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{item['Title']}}</a>  <h5>{{item['Price']}}</h5>
                    <img src="{{item['Imagelink']}}"  height="100"> <h5>{{item['Rating']}} Stars</h5> <h5>From {{item['Retailer']}}</h5>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
 
    <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/food" title="food icons">Food icons created by Freepik - Flaticon</a>

</body>
</html>
```

index2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css.css') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='diet.png') }}">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FoodPrice</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    


        <form action="" method="post">
                    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                    {{form.csrf_token}}
                    {{form.text.label}} <br>
                    {{form.text(size=30)}}
                    <button class="submit-button">{{form.submit()}}</button>
                   
                
                    
              
         
            
    
                <div class="fixed">
                    {{ form2.hidden_tag() }}
                    {{form2.csrf_token}}
                    {{form2.RetailerFRes.label}} <br>
                    {{form2.RetailerFRes(size=3)}} <br>
                    {{form2.submit2()}}

                </div>
        </form>
   
 
   
        <ul>
        
            {% for item in items %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{item['Url']}}"   target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{item['Title']}}</a>  <h5>{{item['Price']}}</h5>
                    <img src="{{item['Imagelink']}}"  height="100"> <h5>{{item['Rating']}} Stars</h5> <h5>From {{item['Retailer']}}</h5>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
 
    <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/food" title="food icons">Food icons created by Freepik - Flaticon</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you woodford